# extra fonts in pdffonts in R

Tags: r, pdf, fonts

I have the following fonts listed when I run names(pdfFonts())

```
> names(pdfFonts())
 [1] "serif"                   "sans"                    "mono"                    "AvantGarde"              "Bookman"                
 [6] "Courier"                 "Helvetica"               "Helvetica-Narrow"        "NewCenturySchoolbook"    "Palatino"               
[11] "Times"                   "URWGothic"               "URWBookman"              "NimbusMon"               "NimbusSan"              
[16] "URWHelvetica"            "NimbusSanCond"           "CenturySch"              "URWPalladio"             "NimbusRom"              
[21] "URWTimes"                "ArialMT"                 "Japan1"                  "Japan1HeiMin"            "Japan1GothicBBB"        
[26] "Japan1Ryumin"            "Korea1"                  "Korea1deb"               "CNS1"                    "GB1"                    
[31] ".Keyboard"               "Andale Mono"             "AppleMyungjo"            "Arial Black"             "Arial Narrow"           
[36] "Arial Rounded MT Bold"   "Arial Unicode MS"        "Batang"                  "Bodoni Ornaments"        "Bodoni 72 Smallcaps"    
[41] "Bookshelf Symbol 7"      "Calibri"                 "Cambria"                 "Cambria Math"            "Candara"                
[46] "Comic Sans MS"           "Consolas"                "Constantia"              "Corbel"                  "Courier New"            
[51] "Franklin Gothic Book"    "Franklin Gothic Medium"  "Gabriola"                "Georgia"                 "Gill Sans MT"           
[56] "Gulim"                   "Impact"                  "Khmer Sangam MN"         "Lao Sangam MN"           "Lucida Console"         
[61] "Lucida Sans Unicode"     "Luminari"                "Marlett"                 "Meiryo"                  "Microsoft Yi Baiti"     
[66] "Microsoft Himalaya"      "Microsoft Sans Serif"    "Microsoft Tai Le"        "MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB"      "MingLiU_HKSCS"          
[71] "MingLiU"                 "MingLiU-ExtB"            "Mongolian Baiti"         "MS Gothic"               "MS Mincho"              
[76] "MS PGothic"              "MS PMincho"              "MS Reference Sans Serif" "MS Reference Specialty"  "Palatino Linotype"      
[81] "Perpetua"                "PMingLiU"                "PMingLiU-ExtB"           "SimHei"                  "SimSun"                 
[86] "SimSun-ExtB"             "Tahoma"                  "Trattatello"             "Trebuchet MS"            "Tw Cen MT"              
[91] "Webdings"
```

I would like to use 'Verdana' while writing to pdf files in R.

I am using the following command to specify font for pdfs

```
pdf("abc.pdf",height = 11, width = 8.5,family = "Helvetica")
```

The fonts on my computer include Verdana

```
fonts()
[66] "Trattatello"             "Trebuchet MS"            "Tw Cen MT"               "Verdana"                 "Webdings"               
[71] "Wingdings"               "Wingdings 2"             "Wingdings 3"
```

Comment: Did you use `extrafont::font_import()`? If I use that on my system, I get Verdana listed in `names(pdfFonts())` and can use it as `pdf(... family = "Verdana")`.

Comment: @RalfStubner - I ran extrafont::font_import() but get a message

`/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf : Verdana already registered in fonts database. Skipping.`


and when I try to use Verdana in my code, I get

`Error in pdf("viewport-trial222.pdf", height = 11, width = 8.5, family = "Verdana") : 
  unknown family 'Verdana'`

Comment: And did you call `extrafont::loadfonts()` to register the fonts with the pdf device?

Comment: @RalfStubner - I got it working finally, thanks for your help. Used the steps listed on https://github.com/wch/extrafont/blob/master/README.md.

somehow R was detecting duplicate fonts for Verdana bold and italic and that was causing issues. I removed all Verdana fonts from my MacBook and reinstalled them, then things worked like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused because the installation of R was detecting duplicate fonts for Verdana Bold/Italic and was skipping adding Verdana to the pdffonts when I ran `load_fonts()` from the extrafonts package

so I removed all Verdana fonts from my computer and reinstalled them. Then followed the steps on [Readme](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/blob/master/README.md) for extrafonts package and that solved the problem